# How to fix Indirect ancestor commits in Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have branch with 10 commits (using Gerrit), after going through code review (across the whole chain) I have fixed each commit via `git rebase --i HEAD~<commit_idex>`. After finishing the rebase interactive (I did it couple of times, and pushed a lot of changes with commit --amend, also i have ran into merge conflicts and I have resolved them), I was surprised to find out, that 3 commits from the top (including the HEAD), marked by Gerrit as `Indirect ancestor`.

What does that mean and how can I fix it before merging the code into master ?

Comment: This is purely a Gerrit issue. (I don't know the answer to it, but Git doesn't care about this sort of thing. Git looks only at the commit graph. Gerrit has its own separate identifiers and tracking.)

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, these 3 commits are based on old patchsets of the parent changes, like in the following example:

```
master
      \
       \-- A1 --- B1 --- C2
                    \
                     \-- C1 --- D1 --- E1
```

Commits A, B, and C are ready to be submitted, but commits D and E aren't, because commit D is based on an old patchset of commit C.

You must rebase the problematic commits to the newest parent patchsets (first commit D, then commit E) to get this:

```
master
      \
       \-- A1 --- B1 --- C2 --- D2 --- E2
                    \
                     \-- C1 --- D1 --- E1
```